# Is ListView faster than GridView?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-gridview

I have an app that lists images up until now I've been using and ListView, and is very happy with it, it´s fast and smooth. But now I want to implement a landscape layout as well, and I'm thinking an two column per row type. I got it working and its nice. So now I´m thinking about skipping the listview and use the gridview for both layouts, just use one column in portrait and two in landscape.

**My question:**
Is there any difference in the speed with the two? Is it crazy to use an GridView even if it will work as an ListView?

[image: The layouts]
This is an image to show what my layout looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this and not seen any significant slowdown.  GridView with a single column will look and act just like a listview.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case GridView should be faster because you'll be populating the images into one view only. Where as with the listviews you'll have to do it in two different ones. The latter operation might be a little slower.